# Preventing wireless gateway access when using a separate WAP

Tags: wireless-networking

So, I have U-Verse home internet. Overall, no huge complaints with the service, but the equipment's a little lacking; notably, the 2Wire 3600HGV home gateway has no WiFi-N capability, which was a step down from my old ADSL connection run through a Cisco E3000 Wireless-N router.

A couple of weeks ago, things came to a head when my wife got a new desktop computer for work, set it up in her new home office, and the receiver, literally five feet from the WAP (but through a wall) could not give her a reliable connection. In response, I disabled the wireless features of the 2WIRE gateway and reinstalled the Linksys as a WAP; the gateway still controls service access and DHCP, but the Linksys now provides 2.4 and 5.5GHz channels on both G and N protocols with a much stronger signal strength, especially for the N-capable devices in our home like our cell phones/laptops.

The problem, however, is that all wireless connections now appear to be coming in on port 1 of the wired switch. So, even though I have disabled wireless access to both the 2WIRE and the Linksys, one could still get to the 2WIRE unit through the wireless connection of the Linksys because the 2WIRE can't tell the difference anymore.

Knowing these two models and their capabilities, how can I configure one, the other, or both to flat-out prevent access to either device from anything connecting through the WAP? Obviously both of these devices have password protection, but I'd like that extra step of flat-out refusing the connection in this scenario.

Comment: I'd go the other way around: Put the 2WIRE in bridge mode and put the Linksys in DHCP mode with the 2WIRE on the WAN port.

Comment: So basically all the 2WIRE would be doing is converting the U-Verse WAN to my home Ethernet LAN? It's a thought. If you can guide me through it in an answer you'd probably get the tick as of now.